# How do I interpret the random effect plot?

Tags: data-visualization, lme4-nlme

For example I have the `lmer` model

```
m2 <- lmer(avg_rent ~ avg_age + avg_mrt_dist_f + avg_age:avg_mrt_dist_f + 
            (1|district) + (1|region),
            REML=TRUE,
            data=train_set)

p <- plot_model(m2,type = "re", facet.grid=FALSE, free.scale = FALSE, title = NULL, vline.color = "darkgrey")
grid.arrange(p[[1]], p[[2]], nrow=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Given that you only have three regions, I would not include them as a random effect.